# Is there a way to target Firefox 3.0 and below for CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I have a CSS-specific issue that only appears in Firefox 3.0 and not in 3.6+. Does anyone know a hack?

Comment: It's probably better to dig in to your code and figure out the problem at it's root rather than trying to rig up a fix just for that specific browser. Could you please elaborate on the styling issue?

Comment: FF is up to like version 21 now, and automatically updates.  Why is this even an issue?

Comment: I'm testing in browserstack... I have an <input> tag placed next to a <button> tag, and for some reason these two tags drop down in position by around 50px. And this only occurs in Firefox 3.0. Mainly trying to fix this for my own peace of mind.

Comment: If you can find a single person still using FF3.0 for real, I'll be amazed. I bet there are more IE5.0 users today than FF3.0.

Comment: Okay -- I am convinced that I shouldn't worry too much about this anymore. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 5):

[A quick search](https://www.google.com/search?q=firefox+3.0+css+hack) reveals the answer:

```
html>/**/body .yourSelector, x:-moz-any-link { } /* Only FireFox 2 */
html>/**/body .yourSelector, x:-moz-any-link, x:default { } /* Only FireFox 3 */
```

Sources:

- http://perishablepress.com/css-hacks-for-different-versions-of-firefox/
- http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/

However:

Chances are good that you don't need a hack. Validate your HTML and CSS first, invalid HTML is often the cause of layout issues in many browsers: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks! I tried using html>/**/body .container, x:-moz-any-link, x:default {
position: relative;
top:-50px; }, but it doesn't work well with LESS... and other hacks I found applied to 3.6 as well as 3.0, which was problematic since the differences are pretty big. Am going to look into html/css validation.

Comment: What does it have to do with LESS? You mean the CSS you typed was destroyed after processing? I gotta agree with the comments, I wouldn't sweat FF3 too much, it's pretty old school.

Comment: Hi, there was  only 1 case where i add to use this hack. 99.99% of the time, it can be solved.  So without your HTML & CSS , i believe it is not reasonnable to use this hack.At least you need to know why and explain what you 're asking it for.